# Internal Site Search

Tags: web-applications, go, elasticsearch

I'm learning to develop web applications and I would like to create my own internal site search engine (without using Google or a 3rd party hosting service) that could index my web app. Could I go about using something like Elastic Search for a small web app? I have been reading about it, but I have only seen it used for big sites/apps. Or would I have to implement this myself without any 3rd party APIs? I'm using Golang as my programming language.

Comment: Elasticsearch would do just fine for this. All you need to interface with it is an HTTP library and time to read the documentation.

Comment: If you are using PostgreSQL - the full text search (FTS) capabilities may also suit. Will depend on your need. For a smaller site that needs a documentation search, article/blog post search, etc - it is more than capable. http://blog.lostpropertyhq.com/postgres-full-text-search-is-good-enough/ - I use Postgres FTS + https://github.com/jmoiron/sqlx for my own web app.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Bleve](http://www.blevesearch.com) - it's pure Go ElasticSearch/Lucene alternative. Looks promising.

Here is nice talk about Bleve at FOSDEM'15 Go DevRoom: https://video.fosdem.org/2015/devroom-go/bleve.mp4 (145M)